# Overriding method of a class instance in Python

Tags: python, overriding, instance

I have an instance `bear` of some unknown class with a method `size` that returns a number. So for example:

```
bear.size()
```

will do some calculation and return a number, let's say 3.

I want to override this method so it returns double whichever number it is, so `bear.size()` will return 6.

When I try to implement it I get a recursion error, since the new method calls itself. So when I run:

```
from types import MethodType

class Animal():
    def size(self):
        return 3
bear = Animal()

def new_size(self):
    return self.size() * 2

bear.size() # returns 3. 
bear.size = MethodType(new_size, bear)
bear.size() # should return 6.
```

I get `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. How should I overwrite the method?

Thanks!

Comment: Assigning to `bear.size` creates a new, callable *instance* attribute (the value being a new bound method) that shadows the class attribute `Animal.size`. Overriding methods on a per-instance basis doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Of course there is recursion, it is calling itself over and over again, **you assigned it to `self.size`**. If you want to keep that, I guess you could use `Animal.size(self)` but I question the wisdom of mucking with your instance like this in the first place

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it's for an edge case, so it's either this or finding and changing the original block of code, which is a central piece and would have to be compatible with the rest of the project. But it's very hacky, I agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can stash the old implementation on the instance so you can call it in the overridden version.

```
from types import MethodType


class Animal:
    def size(self):
        return 3


bear = Animal()


def new_size(self):
    return self._old_size() * 2


bear.size()  # returns 3.
bear._old_size = bear.size
bear.size = MethodType(new_size, bear)
print(bear.size())  # should return 6.
```

Alternately, call the unbound original method with `self`:

```
from types import MethodType


class Animal:
    def size(self):
        return 3


bear = Animal()


def new_size(self):
    return Animal.size(self) * 2


bear.size()  # returns 3.
bear.size = MethodType(new_size, bear)
print(bear.size())  # should return 6.
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @AKX solution, you can also use decoration and decorate your function:

```py
def double_size(fn):
    def wrapper():
        return fn() * 2
    return wrapper

bear.size()
bear.size = double_size(bear.size)
bear.size()
```

Comment: Thanks! Pretty elegant solution.